# .NET 5 upgrade causes 'Assembly not strong-named or is tampered' exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, .net-5

I have upgraded my WPF project from .NET core 3.1 to 5. I started to get error while loading one of my 3rd-party DLLs. I see the following error:

InnerException = {"Strong name validation for the assembly 'Abt.Controls.SciChart.Wpf.2.32'  failed. Assembly not strong-named or is tampered. Verification via API failed."}

If I check the assembly by sn.exe I see it is verified. I had no poblum with .NET Core 3.1. I could not find any reason afte reading release notes for NET 5. Is there way to get rid of this exception?

[image]

Comment: Using the olden .NET Framework version of sn.exe doesn't help you.  Google ".net enhanced strong naming" to get ahead.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also with SciChart! Did you ever find a workaround, other than upgrading to the latest version?